# How to disable whole column selection of QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, selection, qtableview, qheaderview

[void setSelectionBehavior ( QAbstractItemView::SelectionBehavior behavior )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#selectionBehavior-prop)

This function accepts one of three values: for selecting items, for selecting rows and selecting cells.

**Question:**

I need the case when clicking a cell, it is selected, when clicking row index, row is selected but when clicking column header the whole column is not selected. As I understand this cant be done using this function.

I need the tableview to behave exactly same as when `SelectionBehavior::selectItems` is set.

But when user clicks on header the column should not be selected.

I am thinking about disabling column selection from `QHeaderView` but can't find how?

Comment: Did you try to filter click events on the specific section of the header view?

Answer (score 3):

From my application:

```
    // get header from QTableView tableView (replace with your widget name)
    QHeaderView *header = new QHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal, tableView);
#if QT_VERSION < 0x50000
// Qt 4.8.1
    header->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
#else
// Qt 5.2.0
    header->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
#endif
    header->setHighlightSections(false); // this is what you want
```

setHighlightSections(bool) slot is valid for Qt 4 and Qt 5

**EDIT:**
Excuse for carelessness! This only works if you use SelectRows or SelectItems with SingleSelection. You can find proof in the sources `qheaderview.cpp` and `qtableview.cpp`, slots  `voidQHeaderView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);` and  `voidQTableViewPrivate::selectColumn(int column, bool anchor);`

For SelectItems can be used this slot:

```
    header->setClickable(false);
```

Comment: This doesn't helped. I think it is about highlighting the sections, not about selecting the columns. Can you please double check it?

Comment: You right! My case is SelectRows. If you not use any clicks on the headers, you can disable selection of column with setClickable(false). I edited my answer.

Comment: `setClickable` is now obsolete; use `setSectionsClickable` instead:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qheaderview-obsolete.html#setClickable